# swift, write code for ios 7 and 8

Tags: ios, swift

i got an test app I'm writing with Swift, I want to target iOS 7.  But enable local notification I need to add

```
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound 
    | UIUserNotificationType.Alert 
    | UIUserNotificationType.Badge, 
    categories: nil))
```

But this call is not available in iOS 7, so I added

```
var version:NSString = UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion as NSString;
if  version.doubleValue >= 8 {
    // ios 8 code
}
```

The ios 8 code block is only run in under iOS 8 (Tested), but when run the app in iOS 7 I still get

> dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIUserNotificationSettings
>     Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/AC73969D-1A4C-45AC-99CA-0B3982C1EE36/Timely.app/Timely
>     Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
>    in /var/mobile/Applications/AC73969D-1A4C-45AC-99CA-0B3982C1EE36/Timely.app/Timely

I assume it's because the binary contains symbol to api that doesn't exist in iOS 7, but how do i resolve this?

Comment: When do you see this error?

Comment: when start the app, but i have this block in the app delegate, the code works in ios 8 and no error remove the block in ios 7

Comment: You are compiling this with the right sdk, don't you? So even if you launch this app on an iOS7 device, you should compile it with the latest base sdk…

Comment: What happens if you change your project's target to iOS7? I'm guessing (at the moment at least in the betas) that when you compile the App it goes ahead and puts all the iOS8 symbols in anyway and when it comes to `dyld` to link everything together on iOS7 it finds a whole bunch of iOS8-isms it doesn't understand.

Comment: afaik you don't get the option to deploy on ios 7 if deployment target isn't ios 7 or lower

Comment: It's compiled with ios 8 sdk

Comment: Any luck? I am now also stuck with this issue...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Swift preprocessor equivalent to iOS version check comparison?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166919/what-is-the-swift-preprocessor-equivalent-to-ios-version-check-comparison)

Comment: This seems to be fixed in Xcode 6 beta 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think you are running into a current limitation, see this

[What is the Swift preprocessor equivalent to iOS version check comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166919/swift-preprocessor-equivalent-to-ios-version-check-comparison-is)

The only way to get around this is to add an Objective-C file, and then use `#if` macros and make two helper functions that you call from Swift (one for iOS8 and one for iOS7).  I expect this will be fixed at some point.

Comment: `#if` is not suitable here. the system version is not decided at compile-time. same binary can be used on ios7 and ios8

Comment: this actually did work, by check UIDevice system version in objc, app didn't complain about unknow symbol, pitty it's such a hack

Comment: It's just for now.  I am pretty sure this is a bug.  You might want to file a Radar.

Comment: You don't need an `#if` because as Bryan Chen said, the problem is runtime, not compile time. This only "works" by shifting the code to Objective-C, which we already know doesn't have this problem. (The Objective-C compiler properly weak-links symbols that are only available on later versions than the deployment target.)

Answer (score 1):

In Beta6 it appears that some (all?) of the linking problems have been fixed.  Apps linked with UIAlertAction and UIAlertController used to fail to launch on 7.1, but now will launch.  You still cannot use them in 7.1, but you can test for iOS version and use the older objects.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, so for anyone having this, here is another possible solution:

If you go to your Target > General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries, you should see UIKit (if not, add it). Make sure it says "Optional" instead of "Required" next to it...

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a dirty hack but it works for me:

```
if(UIApplication.sharedApplication().respondsToSelector("isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications")){ println("is iOS8") }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24773465/1390251) by *[Prasath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3560390/prasath)*, but it is written in *Objective-C*,
so I have written something similar in *swift*:

(tested in *Xcode 6* )

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

   // ...

   // Set Notification

   if UIApplication.sharedApplication().respondsToSelector(Selector("registerUserNotificationSettings:")) {

      // Notifications for iOS 8
      let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert | .Sound, categories: nil)
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
   }
   else {
      // Notifications for iOS < 8
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(.Alert | .Sound)
   }

   // ...

   return true
}
```

Hope that helps