# Check for class existence in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use NSURLQueryItem in my Swift iOS app. However, that class is only available since iOS 8, but my app should also run on iOS 7. How would I check for class existence in Swift?

In Objective-C you would do something like:

```
if ([NSURLQueryItem class]) {
    // Use NSURLQueryItem class
} else {
    // NSURLQueryItem is not available
}
```

Related to this question is: How do you check for method or property existence of an existing class?

There is a nice section in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW4 called ***Supporting Multiple Versions of iOS***, which explains different techniques for Objective-C. How can these be translated to Swift?

Comment: Check out this answer, it worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24956190/84745

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Swift 2.0 provides us with a simple and natural way to do this.It is called API Availability Checking.Because `NSURLQueryItem` class is only available since iOS8.0,you can do in this style to check it at runtime.

```
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        // NSURLQueryItem is available

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

Comment: does this work for classes which are platform dependant, eg HealthKit?

Answer (score 16):

Simplest way I know of

```
if NSClassFromString("NSURLQueryItem") != nil {
    println("NSURLQueryItem exists")
}else{
    println("NSURLQueryItem does not exists")
}
```

Comment: While this solution works fine with debug settings, but it fails when the app build with release settings.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
if objc_getClass("NSURLQueryItem") != nil {
   // iOS 8 
} else {
   // iOS 7
}
```

I've also done it like this too:

```
if let theClass: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("NSURLQueryItem") {
    // iOS 8
} else {
    // iOS 7
}
```

Or, you can also check system version like so, but this isn't the best practice for iOS dev - really you should check if a feature exists. But I've used this for a few iOS 7 hacks... pragmatism over purity.

```
    switch UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare("8.0.0", options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) {
    case .OrderedSame, .OrderedDescending:
        iOS7 = false
    case .OrderedAscending:
        iOS7 = true
    }
```

Comment: That "if let theClass" was most useful in my case, where I first need to check if 3rd party class exists and then use it.