# How to don't start a method in iOS7

Tags: ios, swift

How I can let's start the following method only if is >= 8.0 ?
It's in the TabBarController class.

```
let floatVersion = (UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion as NSString).floatValue

func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, animationControllerForTransitionFromViewController fromVC: UIViewController, toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    //   if ( floatVersion >= 8.0) {

    let transitioningObject: TransitioningObject = TransitioningObject()
    transitioningObject.tabBarController = self
    return transitioningObject
    //}
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong if you uncomment the if condition?

Comment: Look `-> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? `. The function need to have something to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166919/what-is-the-swift-preprocessor-equivalent-to-ios-version-check-comparison) for verifying system version.

You're on the right track already, just handle the `if` as you do for `iOS >= 8.0`, and else call an iOS7 alternative and return nil

```
let floatVersion = (UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion as NSString).floatValue

func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, animationControllerForTransitionFromViewController fromVC: UIViewController, toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    if ( floatVersion >= 8.0) {

    let transitioningObject: TransitioningObject = TransitioningObject()
    transitioningObject.tabBarController = self
    return transitioningObject
    }else {
      //do something else here if it's iOS7 or earlier?
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your method return optional UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning you can return nil if version is lower then 8.0

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, animationControllerForTransitionFromViewController fromVC: UIViewController, toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
   if ( floatVersion >= 8.0) {

       let transitioningObject: TransitioningObject = TransitioningObject()
       transitioningObject.tabBarController = self
       return transitioningObject
    }else{
       return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, assuming your code may run on something below iOS 8 (which only seems reasonable, given your question) is to compare it to `-[UIDevice systemVersion]`. Check out the following Swift code:

```
switch UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare("8.0.0", options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) {
case .OrderedSame, .OrderedDescending:
    println("iOS >= 8.0")
case .OrderedAscending:
    println("iOS < 8.0")
}
```

The above was borrowed from NSHipster. There's a better way to do this if your code won't run on a device running below iOS 8 (probably only really useful once iOS 9 comes around). See [here](http://nshipster.com/swift-system-version-checking/) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

```
let iosVersion = (UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion as NSString).floatValue

func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, animationControllerForTransitionFromViewController fromVC: UIViewController, toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

    switch iosVersion.compare("8.0.0", options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch)
    {
        case .OrderedSame, .OrderedDescending:
            //iOS>=8.0.0
            let transitioningObject: TransitioningObject = TransitioningObject()
            transitioningObject.tabBarController = self
            return transitioningObject
        case .OrderedAscending:
            //iOS<8.0.0
            return nil
    }
}
```