# Negate #available statement

Tags: ios, swift

I want to execute a code block only on devices running with an OS older than `iOS8`. I can't do:

```
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) == false {
    doFoo() 
}
```

The solution I'm using for now is:

```
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) { } else { 
    doFoo() 
}
```

, but it feels clunky. Is there another way to negate the `#available` statement elegantly with Swift ?

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to check the OS version. The proper thing is to see if a class or method exists.

Comment: @rmaddy what you're saying isn't true at all. There's a portion in the WWDC videos in which references to do exactly this.

Comment: @rmaddy read such https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/hi-im-available/.

Comment: @TheCodingArt What I said was true. However, based on the "But You Told Me Earlier…" section of the article you linked, it's no longer true in Swift, as of Swift 2 (but still true for Objective-C). Good to know.

Comment: @rmaddy Read my response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166919/what-is-the-swift-preprocessor-equivalent-to-ios-version-check-comparison/38362225#38362225. There are defined constants in iOS Apple provided specifically for checking the version number via `NSFoundationNumber`. There's also `NSProcessInfo().isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion` for further specifics. Both of which are available in Objc. `NSFoundationNumber` has been around for quite some time.

Comment: @rmaddy it's typically considered bad practice to test the existence of a method for multiple reasons. One being, a method can exist via private Apple frameworks and respond regardless if it's publicly available or not. UICollectionView contained many of the exposed methods prior to being available to the developer community.

Comment: as a note for @tomahh, unfortunately, I have not found a proper solutions to provide a range of iOS versions or to allow code implementation for only an earlier version of iOS. I'm beyond surprised we can't do something along the lines of: `#available(iOS 8.0, <)` or  `#available(iOS 8.0, *, iOS 9.0)`. Still hoping/looking.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Swift 5.6, you can now do the following:

```
if #unavailable(iOS 15) {
    // Under iOS 15
} else {
    // iOS 15+
}
```

Or just the following depending on your case:

```
if #unavailable(iOS 15) {
    // Under iOS 15
}
```

This is part of [SE-0290: Negative availability](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0290-negative-availability.md).

Answer (score 34):

I use a `guard` for this:

```
guard #available(iOS 8.0, *) else {
    // Code for earlier OS
}
```

There's slight potential for awkwardness since `guard` is required to exit the scope, of course. But that's easy to sidestep by putting the whole thing into its own function or method:

```
func makeABox()
{
    let boxSize = .large

    self.fixupOnPreOS8()

    self.drawBox(sized: boxSize)
}

func fixupOnPreOS8()
{
    guard #available(iOS 8, *) else {
        // Fix up
        return
    }
}
```

which is really easy to remove when you drop support for the earlier system.

Comment: Using `guard` for this feels pretty Swifty if you ask me — nice hack! :-)

Comment: Not sure I agree.. Guard forces a return which doesn't work everywhere

Answer (score 9):

It is not possible to have logic around the `#available` statement.

Indeed, the statement is used by the compiler to infer what methods can be called within the scope it embraces, hence nothing can be done at runtime that would conditionally execute the block.

It is possible though to combine conditions, using a comma, as follows

```
if #available(iOS 8.0, *), myNumber == 2 {
  // some code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems it's the best solution, before Swift2 you had to use other methods such as using ready-to-use classes wrote by individuals. But that's fine, you can set a variable in `viewDidLoad()` and use it to detect the older devices:

```
var isNewerThan8: Bool = false

func viewDidLoad(){
   if #available(iOS 8.0, *) { 
      isNewerThan8 = true
   } else { 
      isNewerThan8 = false
   }
}

func myFunction(){
   if isNewerThan8 {
     //foo
   }else{
    //boo
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5.6**

```
if #unavailable(iOS 13, *) {
   // below iOS 13
} else {
  // iOS 13 and above
}
```

**Swift 5.5 and earlier**

a simple way to check is by using `#available` with a `guard` statement

```
guard #available(iOS 13, *) else {
   // code for earlier versions than iOS 13
   return
}
```

another way is to use if/else

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {} else {
    // code for earlier versions than iOS 13
}
```